# How do you filter in empty cells in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I'm doing a quality flag pass using a column called secPrecipSciRvwQF and I only want the empty cells in my to appear on my graph from my code the quality flag test for precipitation goes by 1 = fail , 0  = pass and empty cells equal not reviewed and are considered as a pass. Naturally, I would only do a zero pass for my graph but unfortunately the data table I'm working with only has 1s and empty cells so I need to filter in with the empty cells the problem is every time I try to filter with is.na I get the error bar “Faceting variables must have at least one value”. I'm new to R I understand that filtering empty cells in a over yearlong data frame might not work but there are more empty cell values then there are 1s in this data frame, I'm lost could someone help me with this I've tried everything I just want to filter and these empty cell values into my ggplot graph. I listed a table of the data frame I'm using for reference and help with my question don't worry if its not within the filter range it all similar to what in my filter range. Look at the aes I'm using and what I'm trying to filter so that it will clarify what Im asking.

```
library(neonUtilities)
require(ggplot2)
require(dplyr)
require(lubridate)
require(scales)
require(gridExtra)
require(ggthemes)
require(ggplot2)
require(plotly)
require(scales)
require(gridExtra)
require(ggthemes)
require(lubridate)
require(dplyr)
require(tidyquant)
library(plyr)
  FPrecipA17D20 <- zSECPRE30min %>% 
  filter(secPrecipSciRvwQF=='is.na'&
                  startDateTime>=as.POSIXct("2019-08-01 00:00:00")&
           startDateTime<=as.POSIXct("2020-12-31 23:30:00"))%>%
  ggplot(data=., 
         aes(yday(startDateTime), secPrecipBulk))+
  geom_col(stat="identity", colour="dark blue") + 
  xlab("Date") + ylab("Halfy Hourly Bulk Secondary Precipitation (millimeters)") +
  facet_grid(.~year(startDateTime), scales = "free_x")+
        scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(31,61,91,121,151,181,211,241,271,301,331,361),limits=c(1,367),
                     labels=c("J","F","M","A","M","J","J","A","S","O","N","D"),
                     expand=c(0,0))+
  labs(y=expression("0 QF Pass Halfy Hourly Bulk Secondary Precipitation (millimeters)"),
       x = "Month") +
  ggtitle("30 Min Bulk Secondary Precipitation - NEON Jornada LTER") +
  theme(text = element_text(size=6))
FPrecipA17D20
Error: Faceting variables must have at least one value
```

```
> list(zSECPRE30min)
[[1]]
   domainID siteID horizontalPosition verticalPosition       startDateTime
1       D14   JORN                  0               40 2017-03-01 00:00:00
2       D14   JORN                  0               40 2017-03-01 00:30:00
3       D14   JORN                  0               40 2017-03-01 01:00:00
4       D14   JORN                  0               40 2017-03-01 01:30:00
5       D14   JORN                  0               40 2017-03-01 02:00:00
6       D14   JORN                  0               40 2017-03-01 02:30:00
7       D14   JORN                  0               40 2017-03-01 03:00:00
8       D14   JORN                  0               40 2017-03-01 03:30:00
9       D14   JORN                  0               40 2017-03-01 04:00:00
10      D14   JORN                  0               40 2017-03-01 04:30:00
11      D14   JORN                  0               40 2017-03-01 05:00:00
12      D14   JORN                  0               40 2017-03-01 05:30:00
13      D14   JORN                  0               40 2017-03-01 06:00:00
14      D14   JORN                  0               40 2017-03-01 06:30:00
15      D14   JORN                  0               40 2017-03-01 07:00:00
16      D14   JORN                  0               40 2017-03-01 07:30:00
17      D14   JORN                  0               40 2017-03-01 08:00:00
18      D14   JORN                  0               40 2017-03-01 08:30:00
19      D14   JORN                  0               40 2017-03-01 09:00:00
20      D14   JORN                  0               40 2017-03-01 09:30:00
21      D14   JORN                  0               40 2017-03-01 10:00:00
22      D14   JORN                  0               40 2017-03-01 10:30:00
23      D14   JORN                  0               40 2017-03-01 11:00:00
24      D14   JORN                  0               40 2017-03-01 11:30:00
25      D14   JORN                  0               40 2017-03-01 12:00:00
26      D14   JORN                  0               40 2017-03-01 12:30:00
27      D14   JORN                  0               40 2017-03-01 13:00:00
28      D14   JORN                  0               40 2017-03-01 13:30:00
29      D14   JORN                  0               40 2017-03-01 14:00:00
30      D14   JORN                  0               40 2017-03-01 14:30:00
31      D14   JORN                  0               40 2017-03-01 15:00:00
32      D14   JORN                  0               40 2017-03-01 15:30:00
33      D14   JORN                  0               40 2017-03-01 16:00:00
34      D14   JORN                  0               40 2017-03-01 16:30:00
35      D14   JORN                  0               40 2017-03-01 17:00:00
36      D14   JORN                  0               40 2017-03-01 17:30:00
37      D14   JORN                  0               40 2017-03-01 18:00:00
38      D14   JORN                  0               40 2017-03-01 18:30:00
39      D14   JORN                  0               40 2017-03-01 19:00:00
40      D14   JORN                  0               40 2017-03-01 19:30:00
41      D14   JORN                  0               40 2017-03-01 20:00:00
42      D14   JORN                  0               40 2017-03-01 20:30:00
43      D14   JORN                  0               40 2017-03-01 21:00:00
44      D14   JORN                  0               40 2017-03-01 21:30:00
45      D14   JORN                  0               40 2017-03-01 22:00:00
46      D14   JORN                  0               40 2017-03-01 22:30:00
47      D14   JORN                  0               40 2017-03-01 23:00:00
48      D14   JORN                  0               40 2017-03-01 23:30:00
49      D14   JORN                  0               40 2017-03-02 00:00:00
50      D14   JORN                  0               40 2017-03-02 00:30:00
51      D14   JORN                  0               40 2017-03-02 01:00:00
52      D14   JORN                  0               40 2017-03-02 01:30:00
53      D14   JORN                  0               40 2017-03-02 02:00:00
54      D14   JORN                  0               40 2017-03-02 02:30:00
55      D14   JORN                  0               40 2017-03-02 03:00:00
56      D14   JORN                  0               40 2017-03-02 03:30:00
57      D14   JORN                  0               40 2017-03-02 04:00:00
58      D14   JORN                  0               40 2017-03-02 04:30:00
59      D14   JORN                  0               40 2017-03-02 05:00:00
60      D14   JORN                  0               40 2017-03-02 05:30:00
61      D14   JORN                  0               40 2017-03-02 06:00:00
62      D14   JORN                  0               40 2017-03-02 06:30:00
63      D14   JORN                  0               40 2017-03-02 07:00:00
64      D14   JORN                  0               40 2017-03-02 07:30:00
65      D14   JORN                  0               40 2017-03-02 08:00:00
66      D14   JORN                  0               40 2017-03-02 08:30:00
           endDateTime secPrecipBulk secPrecipExpUncert secPrecipRangeQF
1  2017-03-01 00:30:00             0                  0                0
2  2017-03-01 01:00:00             0                  0                0
3  2017-03-01 01:30:00             0                  0                0
4  2017-03-01 02:00:00             0                  0                0
5  2017-03-01 02:30:00             0                  0                0
6  2017-03-01 03:00:00             0                  0                0
7  2017-03-01 03:30:00             0                  0                0
8  2017-03-01 04:00:00             0                  0                0
9  2017-03-01 04:30:00             0                  0                0
10 2017-03-01 05:00:00             0                  0                0
11 2017-03-01 05:30:00             0                  0                0
12 2017-03-01 06:00:00             0                  0                0
13 2017-03-01 06:30:00             0                  0                0
14 2017-03-01 07:00:00             0                  0                0
15 2017-03-01 07:30:00             0                  0                0
16 2017-03-01 08:00:00             0                  0                0
17 2017-03-01 08:30:00             0                  0                0
18 2017-03-01 09:00:00             0                  0                0
19 2017-03-01 09:30:00             0                  0                0
20 2017-03-01 10:00:00             0                  0                0
21 2017-03-01 10:30:00             0                  0                0
22 2017-03-01 11:00:00             0                  0                0
23 2017-03-01 11:30:00             0                  0                0
24 2017-03-01 12:00:00             0                  0                0
25 2017-03-01 12:30:00             0                  0                0
26 2017-03-01 13:00:00             0                  0                0
27 2017-03-01 13:30:00             0                  0                0
28 2017-03-01 14:00:00             0                  0                0
29 2017-03-01 14:30:00             0                  0                0
30 2017-03-01 15:00:00             0                  0                0
31 2017-03-01 15:30:00             0                  0                0
32 2017-03-01 16:00:00             0                  0                0
33 2017-03-01 16:30:00             0                  0                0
34 2017-03-01 17:00:00             0                  0                0
35 2017-03-01 17:30:00             0                  0                0
36 2017-03-01 18:00:00             0                  0                0
37 2017-03-01 18:30:00             0                  0                0
38 2017-03-01 19:00:00             0                  0                0
39 2017-03-01 19:30:00             0                  0                0
40 2017-03-01 20:00:00             0                  0                0
41 2017-03-01 20:30:00             0                  0                0
42 2017-03-01 21:00:00             0                  0                0
43 2017-03-01 21:30:00             0                  0                0
44 2017-03-01 22:00:00             0                  0                0
45 2017-03-01 22:30:00             0                  0                0
46 2017-03-01 23:00:00             0                  0                0
47 2017-03-01 23:30:00             0                  0                0
48 2017-03-02 00:00:00             0                  0                0
49 2017-03-02 00:30:00             0                  0                0
50 2017-03-02 01:00:00             0                  0                0
51 2017-03-02 01:30:00             0                  0                0
52 2017-03-02 02:00:00             0                  0                0
53 2017-03-02 02:30:00             0                  0                0
54 2017-03-02 03:00:00             0                  0                0
55 2017-03-02 03:30:00             0                  0                0
56 2017-03-02 04:00:00             0                  0                0
57 2017-03-02 04:30:00             0                  0                0
58 2017-03-02 05:00:00             0                  0                0
59 2017-03-02 05:30:00             0                  0                0
60 2017-03-02 06:00:00             0                  0                0
61 2017-03-02 06:30:00             0                  0                0
62 2017-03-02 07:00:00             0                  0                0
63 2017-03-02 07:30:00             0                  0                0
64 2017-03-02 08:00:00             0                  0                0
65 2017-03-02 08:30:00             0                  0                0
66 2017-03-02 09:00:00             0                  0                0
   secPrecipSciRvwQF  publicationDate      release julian year month
1                 NA 20200620T125537Z RELEASE-2021     60 2017     3
2                 NA 20200620T125537Z RELEASE-2021     60 2017     3
3                 NA 20200620T125537Z RELEASE-2021     60 2017     3
4                 NA 20200620T125537Z RELEASE-2021     60 2017     3
5                 NA 20200620T125537Z RELEASE-2021     60 2017     3
6                 NA 20200620T125537Z RELEASE-2021     60 2017     3
7                 NA 20200620T125537Z RELEASE-2021     60 2017     3
8                 NA 20200620T125537Z RELEASE-2021     60 2017     3
9                 NA 20200620T125537Z RELEASE-2021     60 2017     3
10                NA 20200620T125537Z RELEASE-2021     60 2017     3
11                NA 20200620T125537Z RELEASE-2021     60 2017     3
12                NA 20200620T125537Z RELEASE-2021     60 2017     3
13                NA 20200620T125537Z RELEASE-2021     60 2017     3
14                NA 20200620T125537Z RELEASE-2021     60 2017     3
15                NA 20200620T125537Z RELEASE-2021     60 2017     3
16                NA 20200620T125537Z RELEASE-2021     60 2017     3
17                NA 20200620T125537Z RELEASE-2021     60 2017     3
18                NA 20200620T125537Z RELEASE-2021     60 2017     3
19                NA 20200620T125537Z RELEASE-2021     60 2017     3
20                NA 20200620T125537Z RELEASE-2021     60 2017     3
21                NA 20200620T125537Z RELEASE-2021     60 2017     3
22                NA 20200620T125537Z RELEASE-2021     60 2017     3
23                NA 20200620T125537Z RELEASE-2021     60 2017     3
24                NA 20200620T125537Z RELEASE-2021     60 2017     3
25                NA 20200620T125537Z RELEASE-2021     60 2017     3
26                NA 20200620T125537Z RELEASE-2021     60 2017     3
27                NA 20200620T125537Z RELEASE-2021     60 2017     3
28                NA 20200620T125537Z RELEASE-2021     60 2017     3
29                NA 20200620T125537Z RELEASE-2021     60 2017     3
30                NA 20200620T125537Z RELEASE-2021     60 2017     3
31                NA 20200620T125537Z RELEASE-2021     60 2017     3
32                NA 20200620T125537Z RELEASE-2021     60 2017     3
33                NA 20200620T125537Z RELEASE-2021     60 2017     3
34                NA 20200620T125537Z RELEASE-2021     60 2017     3
35                NA 20200620T125537Z RELEASE-2021     60 2017     3
36                NA 20200620T125537Z RELEASE-2021     60 2017     3
37                NA 20200620T125537Z RELEASE-2021     60 2017     3
38                NA 20200620T125537Z RELEASE-2021     60 2017     3
39                NA 20200620T125537Z RELEASE-2021     60 2017     3
40                NA 20200620T125537Z RELEASE-2021     60 2017     3
41                NA 20200620T125537Z RELEASE-2021     60 2017     3
42                NA 20200620T125537Z RELEASE-2021     60 2017     3
43                NA 20200620T125537Z RELEASE-2021     60 2017     3
44                NA 20200620T125537Z RELEASE-2021     60 2017     3
45                NA 20200620T125537Z RELEASE-2021     60 2017     3
46                NA 20200620T125537Z RELEASE-2021     60 2017     3
47                NA 20200620T125537Z RELEASE-2021     60 2017     3
48                NA 20200620T125537Z RELEASE-2021     60 2017     3
49                NA 20200620T125537Z RELEASE-2021     61 2017     3
50                NA 20200620T125537Z RELEASE-2021     61 2017     3
51                NA 20200620T125537Z RELEASE-2021     61 2017     3
52                NA 20200620T125537Z RELEASE-2021     61 2017     3
53                NA 20200620T125537Z RELEASE-2021     61 2017     3
54                NA 20200620T125537Z RELEASE-2021     61 2017     3
55                NA 20200620T125537Z RELEASE-2021     61 2017     3
56                NA 20200620T125537Z RELEASE-2021     61 2017     3
57                NA 20200620T125537Z RELEASE-2021     61 2017     3
58                NA 20200620T125537Z RELEASE-2021     61 2017     3
59                NA 20200620T125537Z RELEASE-2021     61 2017     3
60                NA 20200620T125537Z RELEASE-2021     61 2017     3
61                NA 20200620T125537Z RELEASE-2021     61 2017     3
62                NA 20200620T125537Z RELEASE-2021     61 2017     3
63                NA 20200620T125537Z RELEASE-2021     61 2017     3
64                NA 20200620T125537Z RELEASE-2021     61 2017     3
65                NA 20200620T125537Z RELEASE-2021     61 2017     3
66                NA 20200620T125537Z RELEASE-2021     61 2017     3
 [ reached 'max' / getOption("max.print") -- omitted 67182 rows ]
```

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: ^ Yes, please make this reproducible, and it might help to review your question to see if it can be phrased more clearly. I don't yet understand what you're looking for.

Comment: changed some things let me know if the above items help

Comment: (I would draw your attention to the "Copying original data" section of the top answer in the link above. We can't reproduce your data from the printout provided, since we don't know how they are stored "under the hood" -- this is just how they print out.)

Comment: Perhaps the secPrecipSciRvwQF=='is.na` line is the problem. That will only include lines with the specific text "is.na", when I suspect you are trying to find NA rows. That'd be done with `is.na(secPrecipSciRvwQF)`

Comment: zSECPRE30min$secPrecipSciRvwQF[is.na(zSECPRE30min$secPrecipSciRvwQF)] <- 4
zSECPRE30min$secPrecipSciRvwQF[is.na(zSECPRE30min$secPrecipSciRvwQF)] <- 0

Comment: I just used the code above and it worked thanks for you help